# How to close the window on the latest version of Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am currently using Mozilla Firefox 30.0 and it seems that it doesn't support `window.close()` anymore.

You may refer on the image below or if it is too small for you, here is the
[link](http://i58.tinypic.com/4q0m01.jpg).

[image: Here is my example]

I opened the website of Google using `window.open` and then I tried to close it using `window.close()` but it says *`undefined`*.

Is there any other option that I can using to close the window using javascript on firefox?

Comment: you call .close() on the object returned from calling the open() method, not just on window. ex: x=open("/"); x.close();

Comment: @dandavis, it works the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebug console unfortunately does not display the warning that goes along with it, which reads (in the regular Firefox Web Console}:

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Also [MDN `window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close) states:

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method.

So, you aren't allowed to call `window.close()` on windows that were explicitly opened by the user.

PS: This isn't new behavior, but around for ages (even before Firefox was called Firefox).

PS: To give an example, you are allowed to do something like this, only, i.e. close a window *returned* from `window.open`:

```
var w = window.open("http://google.com");
setTimeout(function() { w.close(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: And every user is grateful for that.

Comment: @rob: actually, i think the capability would be quite handy, and i don't see the problem. if i could dbl-click an html file on my desktop, have it load and run and then close the tab, that would be sweet...

Comment: @dandavis Feel free to toggle the `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` preference in `about:config` then ;)

Comment: @nmaier, I did. It was opened using `window.open();` but it doesn't close either; then I read your comment for dandavis, works like charm. Thanks!

Comment: @dandavis The problem is, anyone could do it whether you want them to or not.

Comment: @Rob: but why would any site do so without reason? the whole point of SEO is to get visitors, not throw them away. a site can run while(alert(122)) and crash the tab. it seems unfair that sites can open(), but they can't close(). it not like yahoo could close google. it just seems to me like the pref default could be flipped, that's all.

Comment: @dandavis Why do hackers deface web sites? There are a multitude of things a site would do to you if you leave such a door open for them.